# Density function of generation function $M_X(t)=\frac12(1+e^t)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions

Given the moment generation function $M_X(t)=(1+e^t)/2$. I  try to find the density function, I used the formula $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$ but after that I have no idea of what I should do.

Comment: Discrete distributions ($0/1$ with equal probability $1/2$) don't have a density function.

Comment: I think there is a theoretical distribution with this moment generation function , maybe poison distribution?!!!

Comment: If you read professor vector's comment closely they tell you what the distribution is

Comment: No (distribution-theory) in here, the tag is referring to something else completely. No (poisson-distribution) either.

Answer (score 1):

A [Bernoulli Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with parameter $0<p<1$ has moment generating function
$$m(t)=(1-p)+pe^t$$
So if $p=0.5$, then...